# Changing text size

Tags: c++

Is it possible to change the text size (not the whole console window) of a portion of words?

For example, if I have something like this:

```
Name:
Jordan
```

I want to turn 'Name:' into a bigger font size and leave 'Jordan' as it is. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: C++ itself knows nothing about the text size. You need to consume the OS specific interfaces for the task.

Comment: This entirely depends on what platform or shell you are using. c++ does not offer a standard solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm using Windows.

Comment: If you're in bash, you can use [ANSI Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to change text color if you just want to distinguish certain lines of text.

Comment: Probably not on the console. You should consider writing some GUI application, perhaps using [Qt](http://qt.io/)

Comment: @JimM Have you ever seen text of varying size on the Windows console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr: Not really, no.**

Consoles are generally things that output plain text in some consistent way. Terminal emulators such as `cmd.exe`, or PuTTY, or your Linux terminal, may well provide a way to change font name and size for the whole window. Furthermore, many POSIX-compliant terminals understand formatting systems like "[ANSI Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)" that give a little control over colours and boldness, and I'm sure that Windows has similar functionality via WinAPI calls — these could be controlled by your C++ program. But none of this can take you out of the consistent-size, monospaced environment.

### Option 1

Create a GUI instead. It seems like this is the direction you are headed, and it is the most appropriate solution if you really want fine, graphics-like control over how your program "looks".

### Option 2

ASCII art:

```
    _   _                        
   | \ | |                     _ 
   |  \| | __ _ _ __ ___   ___(_)
   | . ` |/ _` | '_ ` _ \ / _ \  
   | |\  | (_| | | | | | |  __/_ 
   |_| \_|\__,_|_| |_| |_|\___(_)

                           Jordan
```

Comment: [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org) to the rescue!

Comment: @tadman: Yissssssss